# How to reference a Value in a created object after being created as part of a set

Tags: java

As part of a uni tute[sic] we are creating insurance policies that can be taken out by a user.
All different types of insurance can be taken out under one policy. Most of the basic code has been provided to us.

I have created a set of objects of the CoverType Class and I'm trying to then access the get method in that object to add the cost of all the insurances taken out under the one policy but IT WILL NOT allow me to access the getter. It replies with an error "cannot find symbol method getPrice".

This is the code for the insurance policy

```
import java.util.*;
// Class:   InsurancePolicy
// Purpose: To represent a particular customer's insurance agreement
public class InsurancePolicy {


        //ArrayList<Product> orderList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    private static double totalPolicyCost;

    private static String name = null;

    private static int price = 0;


    private static Set<CoverType> TheCoverType = new HashSet<CoverType>();


    // Each instance will have a unique policy number.
    private int policyNumber;


    private static int nextPolicy = 1;

    public InsurancePolicy()
    {

        this.policyNumber = nextPolicy;
        nextPolicy++;
    }

    // Determine this policy's number
    public int getPolicyNumber()
    {

        return policyNumber;
    }

    // Method:  getPolicyCost
    // Purpose: to report to the caller, the total cost of this policy, based on the covers
    //          that are selected
    public int getPolicyCost()
    {
        // Student must replace the following...

        Iterator<CoverType> iter = TheCoverType.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext())
        {

            int cash = TheCoverType.getPrice();
            int total = total + cash;
//          int cost = TheCoverType.getPrice().next();
//          if theCover     


        }
        totalPolicyCost = totalPolicyCost + 100;
        return 0;
    }

    // Method:  includeCover
    // Purpose: To allow the caller to specify a type of insurance cover to be included for this policy.
    // Returns: True if the cover is now included; if it was already included or was unable to
    //          be included this time, false is returned.
    public static boolean includeCover(CoverType which)
    {


        //CoverType initialCoverType = new CoverType(name,price);
        //initialCoverType = which(); 
        // Student must replace this following:

        //TheCoverType = which;

        for (CoverType element : TheCoverType)
        {
            if (!TheCoverType.contains(which))
            {
            TheCoverType.add(which);
            return true;
            }
                else
            {
                System.out.println("The specified insurance has already been added");
                return false;
            }
        }       

            System.out.println(TheCoverType);


        return true;

    }

    // Method:  lodgeAnotherClaim
    // Purpose: To increase the counter of how many claims have been made against this policy.
    // Parameter: lodgedType - specifies the type of cover being claimed. But only the types which
    //            have been included so far, will actually be countable.
    public void lodgeAnotherClaim(CoverType lodgedType)
    {
        // Student must complete
            for (CoverType element : TheCoverType)
        {
            if (!TheCoverType.contains(lodgedType))
            {
            TheCoverType.add(lodgedType);
            }
                else
            {
                System.out.println("The specified insurance has already been added");
            }
        }       

            System.out.println(TheCoverType);


    }

    // Method:  toString
    // Purpose: Display a textual summary of this object's state
    @Override public String toString()
    {
        // Student must complete

        return "Something";
    }
}
```

The error is on line 50 saying "cannot find symbol method getPrice()". All I want is for this to reference this method from the CoverType class

```
    public int getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable TheCoverType has type Set. This means it is a collection of CoverType objects. The method getPrice() is defined on a CoverType, not on a Set. You need to take the actual objects out of the Set within your iterator loop. Something like `CoverType type = iter.next()`. Then you call `type.getPrice()` instead of `TheCoverType.getPrice()`

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider doing a simple foreach loop:

```
for (CoverType coverType : TheCoverType){
    int cash = coverType.getPrice();
    ...
}
```

I feel this is more readable and less error-prone than using the iterator directly.